# How to use gather on dependent columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I am trying to use gather function on the data but it's not giving the required output.

Sample raw data -

```
id  listen_A  listen_B  speak_A  speak_B  
 1     11        21        41       51
 2     12        22        42       52
```

Required output -

```
id  type  listen_value  speak_value
 1    A         11           41
 1    B         21           51
 2    A         12           42
 2    B         22           52
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to `gather` the data into 'long' format, then `separate` the 'key' column at the `_` into two columns and `spread` back to 'wide' format by the 'key1' with the 'val' column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    gather(key, val, -id) %>%
    separate(key, into = c("key1", "type")) %>%
    spread(key1, val)
#  id type listen speak
#1  1    A     11    41
#2  1    B     21    51
#3  2    A     12    42
#4  2    B     22    52
```

---

Or use `melt` from `data.table`, which can take multiple `measure` `patterns`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("listen", "speak"), 
       value.name = c("listen_value", "speak_value"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:2, listen_A = 11:12, listen_B = 21:22, 
speak_A = 41:42, speak_B = 51:52), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```